# SQL Server Rank() Cap for each column

Tags: sql-server, ranking

I have a SQL query that has 3 `int` columns, and then 3 `Rank()` functions with a `partition by` that ranks those 3 columns.

The question is, I just want to rank up to 5000 for each column, and then stop after that. Is there anyway to do this in a single query without splitting it up into 3 queries? I still want ALL of the data for the first 3 columns, just want `Rank()` columns to go null after 5000.

Each partition would go up to 5000.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a case statement.

```
...
CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (<partition by>) <= 5000 
     THEN <rank function> 
     ELSE NULL 
END
...
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks.  Unfortunately the performance gain is minimal, but I did notice a slight increase in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Joe Stefanelli's solution:

```
;with cte as (
   select a, b, c,
      rank() over (partition by ...) as [r1],
      rank() over (partition by ...) as [r2],
      rank() over (partition by ...) as [r3]
    from your_table
)
select a, b, c,
   case when [r1] <= 5000 then [r1] else null end as [r1]
   case when [r2] <= 5000 then [r1] else null end as [r2]
   case when [r3] <= 5000 then [r1] else null end as [r3]
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

the RANK() function treats similar values as similar ranks and hence NULLs get the same rank. So the solution would be to use ROW_NUMBER().